# How can I filter the first column of various variables at once?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have n data frames, each corresponding to data from a city.

There are 3 variables per data frame and they all have corresponding names (yyyy, tmax, tmin).

I want to filter them by "yyyy".

I have started by creating a vector with the names (chr) of all the data frames in order to use in a for loop.

```
cities <- as.vector(objects())
```

Then I have made some mediocre loop attempts

```
for(i in cities[,1]) {

  assign( i, (filter[i])>=2000 )

}




for ( i in cities) { 

  assign(i, as.data.frame(apply(get(i)[ ,1], function(x) Filter(x >= 2000)))) 

}



for (i in cities) {

i %<>% Filter(i$yyyy >= 2000)

}
```

None of them work.

P.S.: Its a completely different topic to "How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)"!

I don't want to merge anything. I want to keep all n dataframes separate but only containing data ranging from yyyy=2000

Comment: It's a completely different topic. Please remove this duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
for (i in cities) {
  df <- get(i)
  assign(i, df[df$yyyy >= 2000, ], envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```